# OpenTelemetry Propagation in Erlang/Elixir - an example

Tags: erlang, elixir, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I have a gRPC API and want to add Otel based tracing to it. Every request to this API contains trace/span ID, but I am struggling to properly emit child span.

Here is an example from `iex`:

```
require OpenTelemetry.Tracer
alias OpenTelemetry.Tracer

:otel_propagator_text_map.extract([{"traceparent", "00-00000000000000001f28325aa9c79b59-37ab46991f7a64e1-00"}])
_parent = :otel_tracer.current_span_ctx()

span_ctx = Tracer.start_span("otel-test")
Tracer.set_current_span(span_ctx)
# start doing some work
:timer.sleep(100)
# work done

Tracer.end_span(span_ctx)
```

Not sure what is wrong here but I don't see span emitted in the `iex` console.
As I understand when `traceparent` is extracted it becomes parent span automatically, hence the need to change the span via `set_current_span/1`.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved.

`trace-flags` in `traceparent` header point to no sampling hence nothing in the output.

Should be: `00-00000000000000001f28325aa9c79b59-37ab46991f7a64e1-01`

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#examples-of-http-traceparent-headers